# Remove black baseline border bar from ion-item in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How do I remove these black bars from my ion-items? All answers to similar questions aren’t working

[image]

my code, applied no-lines in all places still no luck

```
<ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-row padding-left margin-left no-lines>
      <ion-item no-lines padding align-self-center align-self-start>
        <ion-label floating color="light">{{ "EMAIL" | translate }}</ion-label>
        <ion-input clearInput type="email" [(ngModel)]="account.email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged all ionic versions? Which are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I need for ionic 3

Comment: simple <ion-item lines="none> //Content </ion-item>

Answer (score 3):

In Ionic 4 you have to use `lines="none"` is on the [item documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item/)

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-row padding-left margin-left>
    <ion-item lines="none" padding align-self-center align-self-start>
      <ion-label floating color="light">{{ "EMAIL" | translate }}</ion-label>
      <ion-input clearInput type="email" [(ngModel)]="account.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</ion-list>
```

There are other options, like `lines="inset"` and `lines="full"`, and also it will affect the style of the list elements differently if you apply it to the `ion-list` tag or to the `ion-item` themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In your **scss file** of that page add this :

```
.list-md .item-input:last-child{
   border-bottom : none
}
```